# DotNet.HighCharts Put a chart in a chart in a Bootstrap div

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, dotnethighcharts

I'd like to put a chart in a Bootstrap div. I know how to put a chart in a sample html page (C# Highchart code below):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data = new Data(new object[] { 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 })
            });

        chart1.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
    }
```

on the aspx page :

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div> asp:Literal id="chart1" runat="server" /asp:Literal 
</div>
</form>
```

with Bootstrap, I have a lot of div, completed with HighCharts created by Javascript code(aspx page code below):

```
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       NAME OF THE CHART
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="flot-chart">
                      <div class="flot-chart-content" id="HighChart Chart Created by JavaScript Code" style=" height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
                      </div>
                     </div>
                    </div               
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

So I'd like to know if there is an example/method to have my chart created with a C# code (using DotNet.HighCharts references) shown on a Bootstrap div.

Comment: Nobody has an answer ? Please guys help .

Answer (score 0):

So as nobody could answer my question, I ve found a solution myself:

I only use JavaScript and WebServices to make the HighCharts displayed on the website page.

It s no so difficult to use it, you only need to make the good JavaScript function to be able to use the HighCharts properly.

If you have some questions about how to do it, just tell me .

Thanks to anybody read this post anyway !!

Regards.

FB